# How to handle secure cookies with web crawler

Tags: java, php, perl, cookies, http-headers

I have some tasks on a site in php using nginx that I'm trying to automate. I am able to log in but subsequent requests to the rest of the site fail because of a bunch of cookies I'm not able to capture. When I grab the response header its like they don't exist. All I get is a `PHPSESSID` and `SERVERID`, and I'm missing 5 others, although I can see them in my browser cookies. I think only one of them is being used as a persistent authentication token. Ive tried using `JSoup`, `java URL`, and `lwp/mechanize` in PERL. I should be able to get them since burp was written in Java.

```
http: REMOVED
POST /authenticate.php HTTP/1.1
Host: REMOVED
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US; rv:1.9.2.23)
Gecko/20110920 Firefox/3.6.23
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
Keep-Alive: 115
Proxy-Connection: keep-alive
Referer: REMOVED

Cookie: __utma=35782181.1596497020.1319574836.1319750878.1319821717.7; __utmv=35782181.|1=SignupDate=2011-OCT-24=1;uid="MTU5MTY4Ng==|1319649169|e4db70a9171742176a944f4fdc3613fd963b1b7e";username="dGVzdF9sb2dpbg==|1319649169|b82e24618b06d6b14d7ea64600c84a2d20c3de73"; defaultstat1=10; defaultstat3=10; SERVERID=ww4; PHPSESSID=53a7cd9acbb71ed7e7cc7be680e6c99c; __utmb=35782181.1.10.1319821717; __utmc=35782181; mode=full

Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 57
username=test_login&password=login123&btnLogin=Login
HTTP/1.0 302 Moved Temporarily
Server: nginx
Date: Fri, 28 Oct 2011 17:09:08 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
Set-Cookie: secret=99ba70c185973be0cd25e0f12dd1ea72; path=/
Location: REMOVED
X-Cache: MISS from REMOVED
Via: 1.0 REMOVED (http_scan/4.0.2.6.19)
Proxy-Connection: close
```

JSoup:

```
Connection.Response res = JSoup.connect(url)
     .data("username", username)
     .data("password", password)
     .method(Method.POST)
    .execute();

cookies[] = res.cookies();
```

`cookies[]` only contains `PHPSESSID` and `SERVERID`.

Comment: So what exactly is your question? Maybe you can provide some code?

Comment: How do I retrieve the rest of the cookies. They show up in browser and header interceptors but I cant get a hold of them through my script.

Comment: You must provide some examples. What do you mean by 'the rest...'? What exactly is 'my script'?

Comment: The code is at home. But the only cookies im able to extract from the headers are PHPSESSID and SERVERID.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cookies in your sample are Google's web analytics cookies, and they're set via Javascript. Unless the crawler you're writing can execute Javascript, those cookies will simply NEVER get set in the crawler.

What you see in your browser is utterly irrelevant for fixing this - it's what the crawler sees, gets, and can do that counts.

Comment: Okay. Maybe I will try it in php then. Thanks